# Setting SQLite as my database in laravel 5

Tags: php, database, sqlite, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm creating a small mockup for a social network in Laravel 5. I want to use SQLite as my database to keep things small and local. I'm having some trouble, however, getting it to work.

Here's my code (using blade) where I just use a table to display a row in the database:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Testing2
@stop

@section('content')
This is a second test
<a href="/">Back to page 1</a>

<table>
    <tr><th>Author</th>
        <th>Text</th></tr>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$posts->Author}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$posts->Text}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
@stop
```

"Author" and "Text" being 2 columns in my database. Here is the Route I use to generate the page:

```
Route::get('test2', function () {
    $sql = "select * from Posts";
    $posts = DB::select($sql);
    return View::make('test2')->withPosts($posts);
});
```

I know my database is there, I've placed it in the /database directory of my app:

[image]

Lastly, I modified the config\database.php file to set SQLite as the default database:

[image]

When I try and view the blade page using the Route function, I get the following error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I'm doing something wrong somewhere with connecting to my database, but I don't know what. Have I set it up properly?

Comment: What does your `.env` file look like? It is looking inside your `.env` file first for your `DB_CONNECTION` and then if that doesn't exist it will use the `sqlite` definition you have set.

Comment: This is what my .env file looks like, should I change anything there?

http://puu.sh/onGHZ/a5bca3bcac.png

Answer (score 1):

Place your database in the storage folder and mention the path in the database.
Also you should have the php driver installed.

Do this in the app/config/database.php:

```
<?php
return array(
'default' => 'sqlite',
'connections' => array(
    'sqlite' => array(
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ),
),
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your `DB_CONNECTION` inside your `.env` file as `mysql`.

The line `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),` basically says look in my `.env` file first; if there is a setting set for `DB_CONNECTION` then use that, if there isn't then use `sqlite`.

It's an easy fix, just change the `DB_CONNECTION` config value to `sqlite` instead of `mysql`.